# How to switch to frames inside a mainframe in protractor(not nested frames)

Tags: protractor

I'm trying to switch to a frame using protractor which is inside a main frame.I'm able to switch to the main frame but when switching to second frame facing an issue

> "Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page:
>   window.angular is undefined."

Tried with `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` but didn't work.

code used to switch to main frame:

```
var mainFrame=browser.findElement('frame locator');
browser.switchTo().frame(mainFrame);
```

code used to switch to second frame:

```
var Frame2=browser.findElement('locator of Frame2');
browser.switchTo().frame(Frame2);
```

Can anyone tell me are there any changes required for frame2 to code?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

**if they are not in nested frames** come out of frame1 using  `browser.driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` 
and then go to frame2

Comment: Sorry its not working,as the second frame is in main frame if I Switch out of main frame I couldn't get into frame2 to directly.